# Subscriber Contact Attribute Missing in Parent

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact

Some of Subscribers in our Parent account don't have any contact attributes and shown as Unspecified Contact but child accounts have either mobile or email address for these Subscribers. May I know what kind of situation cause this ?

Comment: Open a support ticket.

Comment: a contact can exist as a mobile contact in a child BU and not be a mobile contact at the EID

Comment: @EazyE Thanks for your comment. My understanding was parent have all contact and attributes of child. Deletion of Contacts have to do at Parent Level.  If that the case , how to filter and delete invalid contacts at parent level.